# Android app to add mutiple record in NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

everyone, I am a beginner of developing android app, currently I need to write some data into a NFC tag to check my own NFC reader program, however, those app I can try can only write one record into the tag, which do not match with my requirement to have several record inside and an AAR record at the end, so I would like to ask if anyone know any app which can provide this functionality or anyone has written such a program before?Thank you!

```
public class Writer extends Activity {

NfcAdapter mAdapter;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
IntentFilter mWriteTagFilters[];
boolean mWriteMode;
Tag detectedTag;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_writer);
    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    mWriteTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };

    //enableTagWriteMode();
    //Intent intent = getIntent();

}

private void enableTagWriteMode(){
    mWriteMode = true;
    mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, mWriteTagFilters, null);
}

private void disableTagWriteMode(){
    mWriteMode = false;
    mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

public void SetTag(View view){
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message1);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message2);
    String message1 = editText1.getText().toString();
    String message2 = editText2.getText().toString();
    byte[] textBytes1 = message1.getBytes();
    byte[] textBytes2 = message2.getBytes();
    NdefRecord textRecord1 = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, 
            message1.getBytes(), new byte[]{}, textBytes1);
    NdefRecord textRecord2 = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, 
            message2.getBytes(), new byte[]{}, textBytes2);
    NdefMessage mNdefMessage = new NdefMessage(
        new NdefRecord[]{
                textRecord1,
                textRecord2,
                NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("android.reader")
        }
    );
    writeTag(mNdefMessage, detectedTag);    
}

public static void writeTag(NdefMessage message, Tag tag){
    int size = message.toByteArray().length;
    try {
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if (ndef != null){
            ndef.connect();
            if (ndef.isWritable() && ndef.getMaxSize() > size)
                ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
        }else{
            NdefFormatable format = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
            if (format != null) {
                try {
                    format.connect();
                    format.format(message);
                }catch(IOException e){

                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    if(mWriteMode && NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()))
        detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);        
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
      super.onPause();
    disableTagWriteMode();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
      super.onResume();
    enableTagWriteMode();
}


}
```

Comment: What did you try yourself? Show some source code, please.

Comment: Please accept I cannot post my code here recently, as I am still not clear about the logic, there is why I want some sample code to help myself. I am making use of this sample http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-to-nfc-on-the-android-platform/ the reason why I feel confused is because I am trying to add a few EditView and a Button, so I can input the value by myself, but with this design, I am not sure how should I modify the intent, as the write action should be in a new function which will execute when I click the button

Comment: I am sorry I could not provide the source code yesterday night, as I left it in the university.

Comment: 07-12 10:01:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(22376): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.writer/android.writer.Writer}: java.lang.SecurityException: NFC permission required: Neither user 10061 nor current process has android.permission.NFC.<br>07-12 10:01:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(22376): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: NFC permission required: Neither user 10061 nor current process has android.permission.NFC.

Comment: It replys me this two errors when I hide the SetTag and WriteTag methods, it seems I nee NFC permission, but when do I need it this time, because last when when I write the reader program, no such kind of message appears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give your application NFC support in the manifest file.

Comment: oh, thank you guy, I added the intent filter but forgot to add the permission.

Comment: If you believe that mine is the answer, please mark it as such by clicking on the tick.

Comment: I can successfully open the app and type the data in the EditText now, however, the SetTag and Write Tag function do not function. I have already declared in the button to call the setTag function when it is being clicked

Comment: Is it necessary for me to build a new class and a new intent to handle the writing part of the tag?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/)(shameless plug) NFC Eclipse plugin for editing NDEF messages, including multiple records in a single message. Comes with a project boilerplate for android too, which I guess is what you're looking for (?).